# Jupyter R notebook library(dplyr) causes kernel crash

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I'm running a new install of Jupyter notebook on MacOS 10.10.5 following the the instructions in the O'Reilly video tutorial (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920044260.do). After installing miniconda I create an environment for the R kernel with:

```
conda create -n jupyter_r -c r r-irkernel r-recommended r-essentials anaconda rpy2 -y
```

Within that environment I can start the jupyter notebook and create a new R notebook.

However, when I try to execute:

```
library(dplyr)
```

I get a Dead kernel error, and the kernel restarts in my terminal.

I can successfully execute:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(reshape2)
```

It's only the library(dplyr) that seems to cause the crash. I've also verified that this happens with both anaconda and miniconda installs.

Output from the crash is:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))
 4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
 8: try({    ns <- loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
 9: library(dplyr)
10: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
11: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
12: withVisible(eval(expr, envir, enclos))
13: withCallingHandlers(withVisible(eval(expr, envir, enclos)), warning = wHandler,     error = eHandler, message = mHandler)
14: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
15: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
16: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
17: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
18: try(f, silent = TRUE)
19: handle(ev <- withCallingHandlers(withVisible(eval(expr, envir,     enclos)), warning = wHandler, error = eHandler, message = mHandler))
20: evaluate_call(expr, parsed$src[[i]], envir = envir, enclos = enclos,     debug = debug, last = i == length(out), use_try = stop_on_error !=         2L, keep_warning = keep_warning, keep_message = keep_message,     output_handler = output_handler)
21: evaluate(request$content$code, envir = .GlobalEnv, output_handler = oh,     stop_on_error = 0L)
22: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
23: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
24: tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh])
25: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
26: tryCatchOne(tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh]),     names[nh], parentenv, handlers[[nh]])
27: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
28: tryCatch(evaluate(request$content$code, envir = .GlobalEnv, output_handler = oh,     stop_on_error = 0L), interrupt = function(cond) interrupted <<- TRUE,     error = handle_error)
29: executor$execute(msg)
30: handle_shell()
31: kernel$run()
32: IRkernel::main()
aborting ...
[I 15:33:17.931 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
```

Any suggestions on what's causing this? I've found a number of references to the jupyter kernel crashing spontaneously, but nothing that seems to be specifically tied to dplyr.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: I removed the tag "rpy2" as it is not involved. The R kernel is implemented in R.

Comment: @Alex, maybe it is better to open an issue on github (IRkernel project: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel)